# Select an item from a selectbox according to a specific column

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'd like to select a specific line according to a column (Xfeld, SAP expert will understand).

Here is my code and a sample of data :

```
 <Select id="areaSelect" items="{path: '/AreaSet'}" selectedKey="{=${/AreaSet}.find(function(o){return o.Xfeld === 'X';}).ZArea}">
     <core:Item key="{ZArea}" text="{Name}" />
    </Select>
```

Sample data :

| "Zarea" | "Name" | "Xfeld" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "Area1" | "Area1desc" | "X" |
| "Area2" | "Cat2desc" | " " |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript code in the XML syntax beyond the specifications defined for [binding](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html) will not work. You can set a selected item by using a formatter in your code. The formatter function will set a selected key when the item is created and the flag in your column is set.

```
<Select id="areaSelect" items="{path: '/AreaSet'}" >
        <core:Item key="{
            parts : [
                {path: 'ZArea'},
                {path: 'Xfeld'}
            ],
            formatter: '.formatter.setSelection'
        }" 
        text="{Name}" />
</Select>
```

In your controller add the formatter

```
...
...
    "com/sap/app/controller/BaseController",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "com/sap/app/model/formatter"
], function (BaseController, JSONModel, formatter) {

   BaseController.extend("com.sap.app.controller.Detail", {
       formatter: formatter,
       onInit: function () {
...
...
```

In your fomatter define a function which will set the selected item key.

```
sap.ui.define([], function () {
"use strict";
return {
    setSelection : function(key, isSelected){
        if(isSelected=="X"){
            var oSelect = this.byId("areaSelect");
            oSelect.setSelectedKey(key);
        }
        return key;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: First thanks, second is there a fastest way to do the same (this works perfectly) ?

Comment: since you're running it through a formatter for each item, it's a slight overhead. But it's too less of a performance issue as such. You could get the selected item from the backend separately which would be better and do a property mapping